# Верстка под смартфон

Tags: css, вёрстка

Приветствую. У меня в руках Huawei Y5c его разрешение

1. экран с разрешением 854 х 480 точек и плотностью пикселей в 218ppi (тех. хар-ки)
2. 320x570 - показывает Я.метрика. Myresolutionis.ru Опера - экрана 480*680 и экрана браузера 300*425; Google - экрана 480*855 и экрана браузера 320*488; UC - экрана 720*1281 и экрана браузера 320*496

Я создал страницу, где css

```
body {
background: red;}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
body { background: green;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
body { background: black;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
body { background: yellow;}}
@media (min-width: 1382px) {
body { background: blue; }}
```

Захожу через оперу фон красный - в принципе, понятно
Когда захожу через Google или UC Browser фон черный - не могу понять, почему?
Ведь я держу телефон вертикально его макс. ширина 720 (1281 - высота)?

Comment: зайдите по этой ссылке из разных браузеров и поделитесь результатами: http://myresolutionis.ru/

Comment: Опера - экрана  480*680 и экрана браузера 300*425; Google - экрана  480*855 и экрана браузера 320*488; UC  - экрана  720*1281 и экрана браузера 320*496

Comment: Про Оперу мини пишут, что она вообще не реагирует на media queries, поэтому вполне логично что берётся дефолтный красный фон, а по поводу хрома и UC, у вас есть такая строка в коде: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`? Без этой строки адекватной реакции на media queries не будет.

Comment: MasterAlex  - не было, спасибо, теперь всё яснее стало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В head нужно вставить

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```